# Using ':hidden' selector to find hidden elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

In jQuery, I can use `$(':hidden')` to find hidden elements, but I don't want to include the 0 size elements (`width=0 and height=0`).

How to achieve this?

I can't just judge if it is 0 size, because if one of its parents is hidden, I also want to select it.

For example:

```html
<img id="e1" width="0" height="0" />
<div style="display:none;">
    <img id="e2" width="0" height="0" />
</div>

<script>
    // I want to select "e2",but not "e1"
    var myelems = $('img:hidden');
</script>
```

I want to select "e2",but not "e1".

Comment: so you want to include only `display: hidden` elemnets?

Comment: @ArunPJohny `visibility: hidden` maybe! :)

Answer (score 0):

use **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** in jquery

```
$(':hidden').filter(function(){
      return $(this).width()!=0 && $(this).height()!=0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (element.is(':hidden') && element.width() != 0 && element.height != 0) {
   //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if one of  its parents is hidden,I hope to select it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method or [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector of jQuery to solve your issue.
For example,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($(":hidden").not($("input[width=0],input[height=0]")));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Check the output in console</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="a1" id="a1" value="a1">
<input type="hidden" name="a2" id="a2" value="a2">
<input type="hidden" name="b1" id="b1" width=0 height=0 value="a3">
```

Try it!!

Comment: Lol! That is just an example! Hidden input elements do not have **width** and **height** either!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the style attribute to `display: none;` (or use jQuery's .hide()) you can use this

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/8pu79w5t/))

```
$('*[style*="display: none;"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('elem:hidden').each(function(ind){
if(jQuery(this).height() > 0 && jQuery(this).width() > 0){
console.log(jQuery(this))
}
});
```